# Modelling the Order Book

Tags: orderbook, regulation

For every country, there are Regulators who monitor and regulate the activities of Stock exchanges etc. Do those regulators also monitor Order books of those exchanges? Do they monitor real time? or at irregular frequencies e.g. daily EoD snapshot? If they do, what modelling approaches such Regulators generally consider?

Any pointers on above line will be highly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: To my knowledge US regulators (the SEC and the CFTC) do not directly monitor order books, they leave this job to the exchanges, who in turn delegate some monitoring to the member firms . They can request data from the exchanges ex-post (for example the CFTC requested and received data from the CME to investigate the May 6, 2010 Flash Crash). After the Flash Crash there has been a fair amount of monitoring to detect Spoofing (the placing of large orders with no intention or ability to execute them) and other prohibited activities.

Comment: @noob2 thanks for this information. Is there any way to access that report and analytical methods SEC undertook?

Comment: FWIW here is the report https://www.sec.gov/files/marketevents-report.pdf